# I want to know whether this series converges or diverges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I have a series
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2^n n!}{5\cdot7\cdot9\cdots(2n+3)}\right)^p$$
and I want to know in what value of $p$, this series converges.
So I applied the ratio test, but the limit was 1, which does not provide any information.
And then, I modified this into the equivalent series:
$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\left(\frac{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots(2n)}{5\cdot7\cdot9\cdots(2n+3)}\right)^p$$
But I don't know what I should do now.
Not restricted in this problem, although I know many convergence tests, in many problems such this, usually I don't know how to determine the convergence of the series.
Please give me an advice.
Thank you.

Comment: Where does the problem come from?

Comment: $$\frac{n!}{(n+\frac{3}{2})!} \sim \frac{1}{n^{3/2}}, $$ so the series converges if and only if $p > \frac{2}{3}$.

Comment: You might want to try the Raabe–Duhamel test. It is listed among [convergence tests on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_tests), but doesn't have an entry of its own on WP.

Comment: @Harald Hanche-Olsen : I checked Raabe-Duhamel test works for this! Thank you.

Comment: And are there some tips for the convergence test? It's quite hard for me to find the method for solving the problem... I think I don't have an intuition. :(

Comment: You mean, for finding out which test to use? That takes some practice. Basically, you try the easy ones first. The ratio test seems natural at first for this problem, since the ratio of neighbouring terms is easy to compute. When that fails to provide an answer, the root test seems natural, though it is a bit of a pain in this case. Raabe–Duhamel is not so well known, but once you do, it is a natural next candidate because it relies on a ratio that you already have. It often cracks the more subtle cases near the boundary of convergence.

Comment: Actually the Stirling approximation (which is not elementary in case you are just starting off with convergence of series and integrals) will give you the quickest result. However setting:
$(2n)!!= (2n)(2n-2)(2n-4)(2n-6)...4\cdot2$ and 
$(2n+1)!!=(2n+1)(2n-1)(2n-3)...3$
there is an elementary way of showing $\frac{(2n)!!}{(2n+1)!!} \sim \frac{c}{\sqrt{n}}$ for some constant $c$. If you want, i can post it.

Answer (score 3):

Do the following.

$${2^n n! \over 5\cdot 7 \cdot 9\cdots (2n + 3) } = 
{3\cdot 4^n n!n!\over (2n)! (2n + 1)(2n + 3) }.$$
Now try using Stirling's Formula to analyze the summands with the root test.

Comment: Here is a link to Stirling's approximation:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation